# How to assign count value to each row in SQL?

Tags: sql

I got a table "Product" and I want to calculate the number of Products which have the same price and assign this number to each product.

Table Product:

| Name | Price |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12 |
| B | 7 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 1 |
| E | 7 |
| F | 1 |

Expected Result:

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 3 |
| E | 2 |
| F | 3 |

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: I tried via  group by but lost information. Than I started with a sub-query and count... It seems extremely easy but somehow I have no clue. I am completely new to SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `DBMS` supports `Window Functions`, you may try the following simple query:

```
select name, count(*) over (partition by price) as P_Count
from Products order by name;
```

Otherwise, you may try the following:

```
select T.name, D.P_count 
from Products T inner join 
(
select price,count(price) as P_Count
from Products 
group by price) D
on T.price=D.price
order by T.name;
```

See a demo from [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/etFRQD1vK14QGtNCHrE3qG/0).

Comment: It's better to tag your question with the `DBMS` you are using and it's version, this help the SO community to provide you with the correct answer.